# Cannot access state variable inside function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a messaging application. I'm retrieving the message log from my backend every 5 seconds with setTimeout and storing it in a state variable. I'm having it also scroll to the bottom of the chat window every timeout, but I am trying to make it only occur when there is a new message in the response object. The issue is that I cannot access the state variable inside my function that retrieves it. Ideally I would compare the response object's length to the state variable's current length to determine if there is an new response.

Here's my code:

```
  import React from "react"
  import axios from "axios"

  export default function Messaging(props) {

    const [messages, setMessages] = React.useState([])

    const getMessages = () => {

      const config = {
        method: "get",
        url: "localhost:3001/get-messages",
      }

      axios(config)
        .then((response) => {

         console.log(messages.length) // prints 0 in reference to the initial state value

          if (response.data.get.records.length !== messages.length) {
            // function to scroll to the bottom of the chat window
          }

          setMessages(response.data.get.records)
          setTimeout(getMessages, 5000)
          
     
        })
    }

    console.log(messages.length) // prints actual value correctly

    // Initial retrieval of chat log
    React.useEffect(() => {
      getMessages()
    }, [])
  }
```

I'm open to better suggestions in handling the logic as well. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What doe you think clearTimeout() is doing??

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking message length before? Also setMessages is asynchronous.

Comment: @epascarello Sorry that shouldn't be there I copied it in by mistake. It does nothing :)

Comment: @EmileBergeron It does. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setMessages` will update `messages` in the next render

With that in mind, you could create an Effect that whenever `messages.length` changes, scrolls to your element

```
  import React from "react"
  import axios from "axios"

  export default function Messaging(props) {

    const [messages, setMessages] = React.useState([])

    React.useEffect(() => {
      // store the id to clear it out if required
      let timeoutId

      const getMessages = () => {
        const config = {
          method: "get",
          url: "localhost:3001/get-messages",
        }
      
        axios(config)
          .then((response) => {
            // store the messages
            setMessages(response.data.get.records)
            // here we tell to poll every 5 seconds
            timeoutId = setTimeout(getMessages, 5000)
          })
      }

      getMessages()
      
      return () => {
        if (timeoutId) {
          clearTimeout(timeoutId)
        }
      }
    }, [setMessages])
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
      // code here to scroll
      // this would only trigger if the length of messages changes
    }, [messages.length])
  }
```

I also added the cleanup in your first effect, so when your component unmounts you cleanup the `timeout` and you avoid any extra request